# foreach on json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, foreach, java-8

I have two java applications. In both of them I am iterating json array using foreach:

```
JSONArray logList = jobj.getJSONArray("creation_time");
for (Object log : logList) {

}
```

In one project there is no error, however in the other there is a red line under `logList` with the error `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable`

I have the same imports in both projects and I am using Java 8. I am really confused why this is happening.

Comment: Please show your imports of both classes.

Comment: Assuming you are using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) class, that would not work because it does not implement `java.lang.Iterable`.

Comment: A for each loop need `Object` implement `Iterable` I suggest you to use a standard for.

Comment: @Logan I am using `import org.json.JSONArray` in both projects

Comment: @EL323 Yes, the JavaDoc is for `org.json.JSONArray`.

Comment: @Logan Why is it working in one project and not the other when the imports are the same?

Comment: @EL323 Do both compile? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the libraries you are using are different:

> For library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

the JSONArray doesn't implement iterator, thus you need for-loop like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < logList.length(); i++) {
            //your operation
}
```

> If you are using below library

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use below approach:

```
        for (Object jsonObject : logList) {
            if(jsonObject instanceof JSONObject)
            {
                //your operation
            }
        }
```

Comment: Turns out I had a json jar added externally in one project (where I was getting the error). I removed the jar and now I can iterate using foreach. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If org.json.JSONArray is the JSONArray you are refering.

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray

JSONArray extends Object. For each loop, as the exception suggest, only support Iterable or array. Iterable is an interface. JSONArray do not implement that. JSONArray clearly is not a array. So neither case fail, thus the error shows.

If you need to loop through its element, you could

```
for (int i = 0; i < logList.length(); i++) {
    Object log = logList.get(i);
}
```

Comment: What's confusing me is that in one project foreach on `JSONArray` is working

Comment: Really? I would like to take a look. I guess, maybe they both named JSONArray but actually came from different package?

Comment: Or different version of JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

The other posters are correct about JSONArray not being iterable, but to answer your specific question...

IDE's can vary the level of error messaging on a per project basis depending on

1. The level of JDK
2. The compatibility level for the JDK
3. Any java annotations for the class or method
4. Java settings on the IDE itself (e.g. with Eclipse you can specify whether each compiler "issue" is an error, a warning or something to be ignored
5. And probably other factors

Try copying the no-error section of code into the other class (with any changes to make it compile) to see if the IDE begins to flag that code.